# Getting wrong time on converting milliseconds to hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: java, android, timestamp, java-time

I know that my questions has been asked many times, but I'm writting it again beacuse I can't resolve my problem.

I'd like to convert a time expressed in milliseconds (I suppose so), to hours and minutes.
I know which is the goal, I mean the right hour and minutes, but I'm not able to get it.

I've tried this :

```
    long elevenPASTEleven= 33240000;  // 11:11
    Date date = new Date(elevenPASTEleven);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(dateFormatted);
```

and the output is:

```
    10:14:00:000
```

I actualy can't understand where is the error.

The long value, in the code, is retrieved from a remote website, which I parse:

```
    Number value: 33240000
```

So I'd like to convert this value to a human readable time, but I can't.

Could you give me any suggestion, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you conclude it was 11:11? 11*60*60*1000 > 33240000.

Comment: Because when I sniff the connection by wireshark, I get the **33240000** value, and **11:11** on the app.

Comment: An other examle is **12.04** which is converted to **31560000** ...
And I can't understand why **11.11** is bigger than **12.04**

Comment: So a later time has a smaller value?

Comment: This question is currently impossible to answer, as we don't know what the rule is that maps times to these values...

Comment: what part of request which the value comes from? can you attach your data sniffed by wireshark.

Comment: The problem was with me @andy, I haven't understood that the value captured by wireshark was for an other time and not for the one I supposed...

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to convert milliseconds to hour,minutes and seconds

```
long millies = System.currentTimeMillis();
long hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millies);
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millies);
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millies);
```

if you want to format your time

```
public String getDurationString(int seconds) 
{
    int hours = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = seconds % 60;

    return twoDigitString(hours) + ":" + twoDigitString(minutes) + ":" + twoDigitString(seconds);
}

private String twoDigitString(int number) 
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
       return "00";
    }

    if (number / 10 == 0) 
    {
       return "0" + number;
    }

return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the "problem"!

It was me who hadn't understood the right time.

The value **33240000** corresponds to **10:14** and **NOT** to **11:11**.

I'm sorry for asking you this useless question, the problem was with my interpretation.

Sorry again, and thank you for help anyway!!!